# Return of datetime format based on userinput choice

Tags: c#

I need a little help with this exercise. I can't figure out how return the date depending on the user's choice (case 1, 2, 3) - the problem is in Concat method, I've tried something but seems to be worthless. The user input is in the following order: on the first line the user enter the day, the month on the second, the third line represents the year followed by a number (1, 2 or 3) on the last line which represent the format of the date (e.g case1: 1 June)!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        string day = Console.ReadLine();
        string month = months[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1];
        string year = Console.ReadLine();

        PrintDate(day, month, year, Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void PrintDate(string day, string month, string year, string option)
    {

        switch (option)
        {
            case "1":
                Console.WriteLine(Concat(day, month));
                break;
            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine(Concat(month, year));
                break;
            case "3":
                Console.WriteLine(Concat(day, month, year));
                break;
        }

    }

    static string Concat(params string[] words)
    {
        int[] integerWords = new int[words.Length];
         
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            integerWords[i] = Convert.ToInt32(words[i]);
        }
        
        if (integerWords[0] > 12 && integerWords[1] <= 12)
            string str = String.Concat(words[0] + " " + words[1]);
        return str;


    }
```

Input:

```
1
7
2020
3
```

Ouput:

```
1 July 2020
```

I hope I have expressed myself correctly so that you can understand! Thank you!

**Edit** For this exercise I can only write code in `Concat` method!

**Edit2** The solution was to travers with for loop over `words` and concatenate the elements in a string which have to be returned and seem to be work fine!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using standard date formatting strings? If this is an exercise I'm not seeing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, but to pass the exercise I am not allowed to changed the template, only in the last part

Comment: So you can only change the `Concat` method? Are you supposed to infer the format choice from the inputs?

Comment: Yes, I can only write code int Concat method

Comment: So you have three cases to check - one has three parameters so that's easy. The others both have two so how would you distinguish between `day, month` and `month, year` being passed in?

Comment: I have no clue, I am still struggling with this but i have no idea how to implement! Any hints is welcomed!

Comment: ridiculous arbitrary requirement with no real world value. Feel free to link your instructor to my comment!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way:

```cs
string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

string day = Console.ReadLine();
string month = months[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) - 1];
string year = Console.ReadLine();

// Instead of having 3 arguments why don't we jam them together
var date = DateTime.Parse($"{month}/{day}/{year}");

// Concat(day, month)
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd MMMM")); // 19 May
// Concat(month, year)
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MMMM yyyy")); // May 2029
// Concat(day, month, year)
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")); // 19 May 2029
```

Comment: Sorry, but for this exercise I am allowed to modify only the last part